# Border-bottom of table header on hover

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

When I hover over one of the headers I want the border-bottom of that cell to be red. Unfortunately, for me it is working in the snippet code so I have also included a screenshot of my problem. When I hover over the header 'Followers' the border-bottom for the whole row becomes red but when I hover over the header 'Following' the border-bottom for only that cell becomes red. I'm not sure why that is and it's even more confusing that it works as expected in the snippet. Any ideas?

```css
.header-1:hover, .header-2:hover  {
            border-bottom: red 3px solid;
            cursor: pointer;
        }


        #list-1:hover, #list-2:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: rgb(238, 230, 230);
        }
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">return to profile</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="header-1">Followers</th>
            <th class="header-2">Following</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="list-1">
                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                  <h5 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
                  <small>3 days ago</small>
                </div>
                <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
                <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="list-2">
                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                    <h5 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
                    <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
                </div>
                <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
                <small class="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[image: image of my problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the default outline color.

```
.header-1, .header-2  {
  border-bottom: white 3px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header-1:hover, .header-2:hover  {
  border-bottom: red 3px solid;
}
```